# Filling the main diagonal of the matrix

Tags: c

Write a program on C for creating and displaying an integer matrix a [4] [4]. The matrix is ​​formed using the index. The matrix is ​​displayed row by row.Can someone help me?

This is what it should look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBvgG.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stack overflow. If you showed what you tried, it will help us help you with the part you are stuck at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    
    int a[n][n];
    
    //creating
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(i==j)
                a[i][j] = 1;
            else
                a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    //printing
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
          printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also fill the array with zeros and paste 1 where necessary:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main()
{
   int matrix[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};

   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
       matrix[i][i] = 1;
   }

    //display
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
       {
           printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");    
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```